# Using forkNumber in jdbc url in properties

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-failsafe-plugin

We are using `maven-failsafe-plugin` for testing and trying to isolate tests in forks.

I tried using `${surefire.forkNumber}` in `testContext.xml`, but that didn't quite work. The database was not initialized with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` in forks. I'm not sure if each fork actually executed `hbm2ddl` create.

```xml
    <context:property-placeholder location="/datasource/${test.datasource:pg-default}.properties, /properties/appInfo.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}${surefire.forkNumber:1}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```

At the moment we are using Failsafe 3.2 with Spring 5.3 and Hibernate 5.6.

Oh. We are trying out different things, but at the moment the properties for datasource was: `jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://appdb.test:5432/test_app`. So we are aiming for using `test_app1`, `test_app2`... databases in each fork.

Comment: Before voting down please comment... Sometimes community websites seem so much worse then ChatGPT as ChatGPT at least tries to be nice and helpful...